# why prime react dropdown not working correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs, primereact

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-4pfqe?file=/src/App.js

can any one help me with this prime component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to add `CSS` of `Prime React` in your `index.js`.

```
import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
```

For more info see https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/setup

Here is the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hoover-qpie1

Comment: I checked several times the docs, how do you figure out?